# How do I activate my child theme, as I do not see it in developer tools

Tags: plugins, child-theme

I uploaded a child theme from Astra, but the css or javascript does not display, but I was told to look if it is activated. I have looked in developer tools, and I do not see anything about a child theme there.
Would anybody know, how I could activate it, if that is the problem. Thanks

Comment: Appearance > Themes, is it activated?

Comment: You should check wordpress.org to get some basic knowledge regarding WordPress. So to answer your question, please check https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#5-activate-child-theme to see how Child Themes work and how they are activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate your Astra child theme from here.

https://wpastra.com/child-theme-generator/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this documentation https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#referencing-or-including-other-files for

1. Referencing or Including Other Files
2. Enqueueing Styles and Scripts

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).